# Use More CPU In Table Copy?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to copy a table with 300mm rows to another with incremental ids so I can test high volume random row fetches without first needed to know the id of the row. To do this, I've created a new table and I am now running `INSERT INTO SELECT` into the new table.

```
INSERT INTO bermuda.users_incremental
    SELECT 'row_number_' || row_number() over (), source 
    FROM bermuda.users
;
```

The initial load of the 300mm table could be done with many parallel requests, and so I was able to complete it in 2 hours.

This copy has been running for 12 hours, and while I don't know how much it's done or how much is left, judging by the IO I think it's only half way done.

IO/CPU is very low, with CPU sitting at 2% usage.

How can I make this process faster? How can I "unlock" the CPU/Disk to run at 100% capacity?
This is specifically a PG question but would also appreciate MySQL responses since I'll be doing the same with MySQL soon.

Comment: Currently DML statements can't use multiple threads in Postgres. Neither for the reading part nor for the writing part. I think the upcoming Postgres 14 will be able to use a parallel query for the SELECT part though (e.g. `Parallel Seq Scan`). But a using a sequence is probably a lot faster than using a window function

Comment: "IO/CPU is very low, with CPU sitting at 2% usage" How is this determined?  Like, what tool is generating what output that leads to this conclusion?